# How to track Facebook sale traffic in GA (gtag.js)?

Tags: javascript, facebook, google-analytics

Google analytics actually shows that payment gateway is the source of traffic that brings in the sale, which of course is triggered by the fact that they leave my website to pay and then it comes back to my website to place an order.

I was wondering if there is any ways to track the customers from where they come from (such as Facebook page) and if you have any suggested workaround. I want to track where the sales is coming from and this is making it a little hard for me.

For now, I have implemented the tracking code GA (gtag.js) in my website, but all I see is just it track the source within the website as if user click product category A to category B based on this tutorial https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/gtagjs/.

I do some research about cross domain tracking here https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/gtagjs/cross-domain, but where do I find the linker parameter? Does this tutorial will help to solve my problem?

One more, do I need to do anything with Google Tag Manager and Adwords?
Really need help, thank you :)

Answer (score 0):

Check that your payment gateway is included in the referral exclusion list. In that case it should be ignored and the original traffic source should be retained (unless the redirect parameter adds campaign parameters of his own).

Cross domain tracking is not appropriate here. Cross domain tracking means to have a continuous session over multiple domains, which requires that your tracking code is placed on all the domains.

Comment: So I checked in my Referral Exclusion List, I put my main website (abc.com). Are you saying that I shouldn't add it there or what? Mind explain further please :) 
Cause what I see, yes there is no record of any user coming from social but just records the referral which is the gateway payment :)

Comment: I am saying you need to add the domain of the payment gateway. Your website domain is in there to avoid self-referrals. You need to add the payment gateway so referrals from there are ignored and the originsl traffic source is retained.